# EF Core 5 TPT and Identity (CRUD)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, table-per-type, ef-core-5.0

I want to use TPT Feature of EF Core and I want to integrate that with Identity but I have some problems with adding to database.

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string NationalCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class Student : ApplicationUser
    {
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string HomePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class Teacher : ApplicationUser
    {
        public string FieldOfStudy { get; set; }
        public AcademicDegree AcademicDegree{ get; set; }
        public int YearsOfExperience { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my database Context class

```
 public class SchoolMgmtContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole,Guid>
    {


        public SchoolMgmtContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolMgmtContext> dbContextOptions)
            :base(dbContextOptions)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
            builder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");
            builder.Entity<Teacher>().ToTable("Teachers");

            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        }
    }
```

All things are ok.

[image]

but I don't know how to insert a new teacher or a new student.

for example, this is the code for adding a new teacher.

```
    public IActionResult CreateTeacher()
        {

            ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(_db.Users.Select(u => new { u.Id, FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName }), "Id", "FullName");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTeacher(TeacherCreationDto teacherCreationDto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newTeacher = new Teacher()
                {
                    AcademicDegree = teacherCreationDto.AcademicDegree,
                    FieldOfStudy = teacherCreationDto.FieldOfStudy,
                    YearsOfExperience = teacherCreationDto.YearsOfExperience,
                    Id= teacherCreationDto.UserId
                };

                 // _db.Teachers.Update(newTeacher); // here I tested Attach - Add - Update, but none of this work.
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(_db.Users.Select(u => new { u.Id, FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName }), "Id", "FullName");
                return View(teacherCreationDto);
            }
         
        }
```

how should I add a new student or teacher? thanks,

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: You add new TPT record the same way you add  new TPH or regular record - by using  some of the `Add` methods,  e.g. for new `Teacher` any of these should do - `_db.Add(newTeacher)`, `_db.Users.Add(newTeacher)`, `_db.Teachers.Add(newTeacher)`. What do you mean by "none of this work"? Are you getting exception or ?

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for your answer, but none of these methods works, yes I get 2 exceptions, first one about DbConcurreny second one is about cant insert duplicate primary key.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I Updated the question with a picture of exception and Add method.

Comment: This is because here `Id= teacherCreationDto.UserId` you are assigning existing Id to the new user (teacher).  Use `Id = Guid.NewGuid()` or just don't assign it and let EFC auto-generate it.

Comment: @IvanStoev if I don't assign id for a new teacher or student how that student or teacher connects to applicationuser ? this is not correct, now I am testing with 3 simple entities (user entity without identity) and with Teachers.AddAsync() I got this exception  ** SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ApplicationUsers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. **

Comment: @IvanStoev why there is no code about CRUD IN EF Core 5 with TPT in Microsoft docs or StackOverflow?

Comment: Hmm, looks like you misunderstand the concept of inheritance. Teacher *is a* User, same for Student. You don't create separate User and "connect" it to Teacher or Student - you create new Teacher which is also a new User. TPT and TPH are just different ways of storing such inheritance data in the database. If you want to "connect" objects to User, you should not use inheritance, but FK relationships.

Comment: @IvanStoev oh ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I  agree with 'Ivan Stoev': You cannot inherit Student and Teacher from User.
if want then your 'TeacherCreationDto' should contain the following fields/payload:

"FieldOfStudy,YearsOfExperience,FirstName,LastName,NationalCode,BirthDate,Gender,Id,UserName,NormalizedUserName,Email,NormalizedEmail,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,ConcurrencyStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEnd,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount" ... The followig coding working for me when I create controller/api by usig auto scaffolder:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FieldOfStudy,YearsOfExperience,FirstName,LastName,NationalCode,BirthDate,Gender,Id,UserName,NormalizedUserName,Email,NormalizedEmail,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,ConcurrencyStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEnd,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount")] Teacher teacher)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            teacher.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            _context.Add(teacher);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(teacher);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this is the sample project that I created with the help of Ivan https://github.com/ArminShoeibi/SchoolManagementSystem

Comment: Well unless your use case implies that a `Teacher` and a `Student` ARE `User`s of your system. But I too agree, generally you LINK your users with your application logic, so in most of the cases a foreign-key is more likely

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough documentation in [Microsoft official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) as the author of the question said.

Contrary to what we expect from TPT, when we want to insert a new record to a derived table we have to provide all properties of the derived type (including Parent type) because under the hood EF Core makes two insert statements, one for parent table and the other for derived table.

So if we provide existing id for making new records, `DbUpdateException` with message of 'duplicate key' is thrown.

I can say that this approach isn't appropriate when we have overlapping in  our inheritance (consider a situation when a User is Both Student and Teacher or even wants to change from User to Student).

As a final word I recommend you to manually create TPT relations. Your models should be like this:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string NationalCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Student 
    {
        [ForignKey(nameof(User))]
        public Guid Id{ get; set; } // Id and forignKey 
        
        /* Student specific fields */

        public ApplicationUser User{ get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Teacher
    {
        [ForignKey(nameof(User))]
        public Guid Id{ get; set; } // Id and forignKey 

        /* Teacher specific fields */

        public ApplicationUser User{ get; set; }
    }
```